# Fill in Form Field from Node-Field using Rules in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, entity, drupal-modules, drupal-rules

I am looking for a way to **populate** some **fields** in an (entity)form (for example name and email) once a client has filled in his tax-number (or another configurable field). The field to compare it to is in another node or entity.

**For example:**

> A registration form for an event => when a user is registrating: check
>   if the filled in tax number allready exists in one of the nodes
>   'attendees last year'. If it finds a match, it takes the date in the
>   'name' field of the node, and puts it in the 'name' field in the form
>   (in the next step, see underneath)

For the forms I am using the EntityForms-module (which creates a form with the fields of an entity, so users can create new entity objects) and a custom module which allows me to go through the form in multiple steps, a rules event is triggered when the 'continue' button in a form-step is clicked.

I have rules and rules-forms-support enabled, I try to make a rule:

- Event: my custom continue button is clicked
- Condition: entered date    from a (to be selected) field from the
  form allready exists in a (to    be selected) node's field
- action: the (to be selected) field from the    node is put in the (to
  be selected) field on the form

I can't hardcode this because it has to be configurable (have to make multiple different forms..)

Comment: passing the form & form_state through the event now using the 'variables' attribute. Now I can use these in my condition and action.. still haven't found it like it should though..

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this via a value in the URL.  Checkout Prepopulate module http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

There is a dev version for Drupal 7.

You should be to add the extra info in the URL in the Rule.